# Remove object in Array of object with underscore

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I would like test if my object is in my Array of object. For this, i use underscorejs and .where method. But, my test don't work :

```
console.log(array);
console.log(object);
console.log(_.where(array, object).length); // return 0
```

I don't understand why, because my object is on the 2nd index in my Array.

I've try to test with `Object.is(array[2], newCanvas`, but return false too.

Anyone have idea ?

Thank you community !

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Presuming your ID is unique (as it appears) you can use vanilla JS for this pretty easily:

`array.findIndex(x => x.id === object.id)`

This will return the index of the object if it finds it OR `-1` if the object is not present in the array.

You could actually remove this in one shot if that's what you want:

`array = array.filter(x => x.id !== object.id);`

Or the slightly longer version:

```
var indexOfMyObject = array.findIndex(x => x.id === object.id);

if (indexOfMyObject > -1)
  array.splice(indexOfMyObject, 1);
```

Comment: Sorry, id edit my message : it return 2. Can i use with underscore for remove my object from my array ?

Comment: Sure, but you can do that with vanilla JS also: `array.splice(2, 1)` - replace 2 with a variable containing the index you previously found.